# LSASS 'Access Denied"

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, administrator

When trying to make a procdump of lsass.exe I am met with "Access Denied (0x80070005, -2147024891)"

I am a local administrator on the machine in question. I have done everything to make a dump file of the LSASS...

I have tried running both Command Prompt and PowerShell as admin. I have used Psexec to get a SYSTEM privileged Command Prompt and was still met with the access denied error when trying to make a dump.
I have tried creating a dump file manually running Task Manager as admin and still got the access denied.

The only antivirus on the machine is Crowdstrike and Windows Defender. I am almost one-hundred percent sure Crowdstrike is preventing the LSASS dump. I doubt anyone will be able to help me with this but have anyone had any luck with something like this before?

Comment: In Process Explorer, check whether lsass.exe is running as a protected process (e.g. PsProtectedSignerWinTcb-Light). See [Configuring Additional LSA Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/credentials-protection-and-management/configuring-additional-lsa-protection#BKMK_HowToConfigure).